# Installed Tensorflow, but get ImportError when trying to use it

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I like to begin with me trying to install the necessary packages to work with neural networks, however I do not have sudo admin permissions, so I had to installed pip. After getting the PATH set up, so that pip would work. Then I tried installing the packages Tensorflow and Keras, like so:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Similarly,

```
pip install keras
```

They start to install, however it reaches the last part and gives me traceback call. So after searching more on web for similar causes, someone suggest to try

```
pip install tensorflow --user
```

Which worked and I got both keras and tensorflow.

However now I am trying to test it out on an example given Tensorflow documentations. Which was the following code:

```
# Python
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

I saved it in .py file and ran:

```
python hello.py
```

And got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "hello.py", line 1, in <module>
  import tensorflow as tf
File ".../.local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
  from tensorflow.python import *
ImportError: No module named python
```

Which I am not sure what is going on, I though I installed everything correctly, but I might be missing things still. Can anyone point me on right direction, thanks. Also wanted to note that this was done on linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work. Thanks to the Tensorflows "installation problem" page, I uninstalled Tensorflow and Protobuf and reinstalled Tensorflow. Which worked :).